# EWS: How to find the ItemId of a ContactGroup

Tags: exchangewebservices

I'm currently using Exchange Web Services (EWS) to create a `ContactGroup` on behalf of a user that I'm impersonating...

Everything works great and here is the code:

```
var email = "frank@mydomain.com";
var accountPassword = "myPassword";
var emailAccountToImpersonify = "steve@mydomain.com";

ExchangeService service = new ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2013);
service.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(email, accountPassword, "mydomain.com");
service.AutodiscoverUrl(email, RedirectionUrlValidationCallback);

// Make sure the account [frank@mydomain.com] is a member of the ApplicationImpersonation admin role.
service.ImpersonatedUserId = new ImpersonatedUserId(ConnectingIdType.SmtpAddress, emailAccountToImpersonify);

// Create a new ContactGroup on behalf of [steve@mydomain.com]
ContactGroup myContactGroup = new ContactGroup(service);
myContactGroup.DisplayName = "Gazou";
myContactGroup.Members.Add(new GroupMember("user1@contoso.com"));
myContactGroup.Members.Add(new GroupMember("user2@contoso.com"));
myContactGroup.Members.Add(new GroupMember("user3@contoso.com"));
myContactGroup.Save();
```

What I'd like to do before creating the ContactGroup *Gazou* is:

- Verify if the ContactGroup *Gazou* already exist (or not).
- If it does, then delete it so it can get created again.

Something like:

```
ContactGroup existingContactGroup = ContactGroup.Bind(service, **ItemId**);
if (existingContactGroup != null)
{
    existingContactGroup.Delete(DeleteMode.HardDelete);
}
else
{
    // Create a new ContactGroup on behalf of [steve@mydomain.com]
    ContactGroup myContactGroup = new ContactGroup(service);
    myContactGroup.DisplayName = "Gazou";
    myContactGroup.Members.Add(new GroupMember("user1@contoso.com"));
    myContactGroup.Members.Add(new GroupMember("user2@contoso.com"));
    myContactGroup.Members.Add(new GroupMember("user3@contoso.com"));
    myContactGroup.Save();
}
```

But I can't seem to know *how* to find the ItemId of that `ContactGroup`.
All I know about the `ContactGroup` is the `DisplayName` *Gazou*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to search the Contacts folder where the group is stored with a Search Filter on the  displayname eg something like

```
        SearchFilter sfSearch = new SearchFilter.IsEqualTo(ContactGroupSchema.DisplayName, "NameOfGroup");
        FindItemsResults<Item> findCgResults = service.FindItems(WellKnownFolderName.Contacts, sfSearch, new ItemView(1));
```

should do it

Comment: Thank you. I changed the ItemView(1) to ItemView(int.MaxValue) because I realized I had duplicate ContactGroup.